# Window not showing up in simulation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've set the background color to green in xCode 7.1 beta version with the following code:

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor] ;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    NSLog(@"Hello");
```

I've placed this piece in `appdelegate.m`'s `didFinishlaunchingWithOptions` method.

`Hello` is being printed in the console window but the background color is not being set to green in the simulation.

Comment: Do you have some root view controller setup or does your app just have a window? The root controller will cover the window which is probably why you don't see the green.

Comment: @rmaddy The file has a default view controller. I'm not sure if it's a root view controller (I'm still a novice)

Comment: Yes, the default view controller is what you are seeing. Change its background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change your background color you have to change view's background color in your view controller, not in your window. You're changing your app background color, not the background of the view you're seeing.

[image]

Use `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];` in your view controller's viewDidLoad

**EDIT 1:**

To see the View Hierarchy debugger, just run your application and at any screen tap the Debug View Hierarchy button:

[image]

Comment: A bit off the topic but the image is too good! :D
If you made it on your own can you plz share how you did it?

Comment: Use the View Debugger: Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy.

Comment: @JAL what for do we have to use it. Can you plz explain?